# streamWriter with format(delta) is not producing a delta table

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-streaming, delta-lake

I am using AutoLoader in databricks. However when I save the stream as a delta table, the generated table is NOT delta.

```
  .writeStream
  .format("delta")  # <-----------
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_path)
  .option("path", output_path)
  .trigger(availableNow=True)
  .toTable(table_name))
```

```
delta.DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, table_name)
> false
```

Why is the generated table not delta format?
If I try to read the table using `spark.read(table_name)` it works but if I am trying to use Redash or the builtin databricks' Data tab it produces an error and the schema is not well parsed.

> An error occurred while fetching table: table_name
> com.databricks.backend.common.rpc.DatabricksExceptions$SQLExecutionException: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Incompatible format detected
> A transaction log for Databricks Delta was found at `s3://delta/_delta_log`,
> but you are trying to read from `s3://delta` using format("parquet"). You must use
> 'format("delta")' when reading and writing to a delta table.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
(
     spark
    .writeStream                                                
    .option("checkpointLocation", <checkpointLocation_path>)
    .trigger(availableNow=True)
    .table("<table_name>")
)
```

Instead of `toTable` can you try `table`

Comment: didn't help :-(